# 'producer' type is unknown to ReactiveAdapterRegistry (WebFlux handler)

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive-streams

I have the following route in my application

```java
@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(UserHandler handler) {
    return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.POST("/users"), handler::signup);
}
```

which is handled by the following method

```java
public Mono<ServerResponse> signup(ServerRequest request) {
    return request
            .bodyToMono(User.class)
            .map(user -> {
                user.setPassword(encoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
                return user;
            })
            .flatMap(repository::save)
            .map(user -> tokenService.create(user.getId()))
            .map(TokenDto::new)
            .flatMap(tokenDto -> ServerResponse.ok().body(tokenDto, TokenDto.class));
}
```

When I issue a valid request to the endpoint, the following error is logged

```
'producer' type is unknown to ReactiveAdapterRegistry
```

Having investigated the issue with a debugger, I see that my handler's signup method completes successfully, so I'm assuming the router doesn’t like the return value, but I'm not sure why?

Comment: When I use `ServerResponse.ok()`, I usually add `.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` (or other content type) before `.body`. Are you allowed to do that in your case?

Comment: Thanks I was missing that but unfortunately that hasn’t resolved the issue

Comment: I would try to separate the code by having the user created in another nested pipeline and then calling `return ServerResponse.ok().body(tokenDto, TokenDto.class);`. By the way, I don't understand how you create a new token based on the user if you don't pass the user at `.map(TokenDto::new)`.

Comment: The new token is created based on the user's ID `user -> tokenService.create(user.getId())` then the returned JWS is used to create an instance of `TokenDto` which is subsequently returned to the client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem with you, the same error.
Finally I change the code using bodyValue method not body(T,Class)，you can try this: `ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).bodyValue(tokenDto)`。

Comment: Thanks, pal. Not working on this project anymore (this post is old,) but I appreciate you sharing a solution for others who face this problem.

Comment: Although I haven't tried your solution, I’ve accepted your answer, because having read the documentation for the method I was using and the method you suggested, I believe you're correct.

Answer (score 0):

try to change tokenDto to Mono.just(tokenDto) it worked for me.
I got the same problem just now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).